# UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.native_init()

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I cloned [this project](https://github.com/acrcloud/acrcloud_sdk_android_extr/) and and copied the `.so` files to my project's `jniLibs` folder.

After that, it looked like this:

[image: screenshot]

However, when I tried using the library it throws:

```
09-18 10:22:53.861 18439-19193/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter W/linker: libACRCloudExtrTool.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x4718
09-18 10:22:53.861 18439-19193/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter W/linker: libACRCloudExtrTool.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x2
09-18 10:22:53.871 18439-19193/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter E/art: No implementation found for void com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.native_init() (tried Java_com_mopo_audiofingerprinter_tageditor_ACRCloudExtrTool_native_1init and Java_com_mopo_audiofingerprinter_tageditor_ACRCloudExtrTool_native_1init__)
09-18 10:22:53.881 18439-19193/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter E/UncaughtException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.native_init() (tried Java_com_mopo_audiofingerprinter_tageditor_ACRCloudExtrTool_native_1init and Java_com_mopo_audiofingerprinter_tageditor_ACRCloudExtrTool_native_1init__)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.native_init(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.<clinit>(ACRCloudExtrTool.java:57)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.createFingerprintByFile(ACRCloudExtrTool.java:0)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudRecognizer.recognizeByFile(ACRCloudRecognizer.java:129)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.TestActivity$RecThread.run(TestActivity.java:84)
09-18 10:22:54.132 18439-19193/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-51298
                                                                         Process: com.mopo.audiofingerprinter, PID: 18439
                                                                         java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.native_init() (tried Java_com_mopo_audiofingerprinter_tageditor_ACRCloudExtrTool_native_1init and Java_com_mopo_audiofingerprinter_tageditor_ACRCloudExtrTool_native_1init__)
                                                                             at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.native_init(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.<clinit>(ACRCloudExtrTool.java:57)
                                                                             at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.createFingerprintByFile(ACRCloudExtrTool.java:0)
                                                                             at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudRecognizer.recognizeByFile(ACRCloudRecognizer.java:129)
                                                                             at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.TestActivity$RecThread.run(TestActivity.java:84)
```

The weird thing, is that the compiled project I cloned is working without errors. I have even attempted copying the classes from [the demo](https://github.com/acrcloud/acrcloud_sdk_android_extr/tree/master/ACRCloudExtrToolDemo/app/src/main/java/com/acrcloud) and still it didn't work.

---

### EDIT

After implementing Divy Soni's answer, the `jniLibs`  folder disappeared entirely. And when I built the app it crashed with:

```
`09-18 11:21:46.848 26158-26798/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter E/UncaughtException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mopo.audiofingerprinter-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libACRCloudExtrTool.so"
                                                                                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.<clinit>(ACRCloudExtrTool.java:56)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudExtrTool.createFingerprintByFile(ACRCloudExtrTool.java:0)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.ACRCloudRecognizer.recognizeByFile(ACRCloudRecognizer.java:129)
                                                                                at com.mopo.audiofingerprinter.tageditor.TestActivity$RecThread.run(TestActivity.java:84)`
```

---

### EDIT2

Please note that the feaures I am using `libACRCloudEngine.so` is working perfectly. So it's `libACRCloudExtrTool.so` that is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

put this line in app build.gradle,it represent the path of .so files.

```
android {
          .
          .
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Please I have updated my question with what happened after applying the answer.

Comment: your new error is because libACRCloudExtrTool.so file is not present in all folders.

Comment: Please I don't understand you. What do you mean by "all folders"?

Comment: mips, mips64, x86_64, these folder must also contain the .so file.

Comment: But it appears to be working in the example project without those others folders.

Comment: I understand your concern, but I have faced same problem,in my case It solved after put .so file in all folders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154771/discussion-between-x09-and-divy-soni).